# Why my jade code does not work?

Tags: pug

I am learning jade and trying to make iteration with it.

This is my jade code,

```
body
  - var users = ['one','two', 'three']
  - var roles = ['admin', 'user', 'stranger']
  for user in users
    - if (user.role == 'admin')
      p #{user} is an admin
    - else
      p= user.name
  for user in users
    ul
      li= user
```

It prints `ul` list, but it does not print my first iteration. Did I miss something here? Should I have to make user.role array? If I should, how can I make them?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your first loop need to work, need as like below code:

```
body
 - var users = [{role:'admin',name:'one'},{role:'user',name:'two'}, {role:'stranger',name:'three'}]
 - var roles = ['admin', 'user', 'stranger']
 for user in users
     - if (user.role == 'admin')
        p #{user.name} is an admin
    - else
        p= user.name
```

Comment: I tried to assign its role with iteration. what I did is `for user, role in users, roles` and `p: #{user}: #{role}` but my role does not print. Should I have to always allocate manually like you did?

Comment: About "I tried to assign its role with iteration", but I don't see it from your original code.   manually is not must.  However, you need make sure users is array of object with name and role.    In your original code, users only a array of string,  it isn't array of object with role and name.

Answer (score 0):

In both for loops you are iterating over a string array: `var users = ['one','two', 'three']`
So in both loops `user` will be a string with one of these values.

In your first for loop you try to access the `role` property of the `user` variable. But since it's a string there is no such property and your if statement evaluates to `False`.

In your second loop you are using `user` directly without trying to access a non-existant property. That's why it works.

Comment: Thank you for nice explain 洋葱头.